# Why can't I change column properties of derby db using dbeaver?

Tags: java, derby, dbeaver

I am trying to customize the Floreant POS to meet local regulations.
I need to change the check numeration and make it start at 0200000001.
I found the ID column in the TICKET table, and in the properties it says that it starts from 0. 
I tried changing it using dbeaver but there is no option to modify the values.
How can I change it to start from 0200000001? It must include the 0 at the beginning.
Thanks

Comment: Is it mandatory that you change it using dbeaver? Or would it be OK to change it using the underlying Derby software? There are instructions about how to change the start value here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860 See the `RESTART WITH`. I'm not sure what you mean by 'It must include the 0 at the beginning', though; Derby generated sequences are just integers, Derby doesn't control the formatting.

Comment: no, it doesn't have to be dbeaver. I will check that link. to meet local regulations the receipts must be numbered in that way, including the 0 at the beginning

Comment: I looked at that link but don't know how to use that information, sorry newbe here

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the value of a column using DBeaver, you can simply select the column and press `Shift + Enter`.
A new editor will open where you can easily change the value of the column.